# .tar archive files EACH to its own directory?

Tags: linux, directory, tar

I have an archive that contains files from various directories (created with -T option, so I used file with list of files to archive). Files preserve owners and rights.

Content is like:

```
var/lib/prog1/backups/file1.db
var/lib/prog2/file.file
etc/prog3/my.conf
```

Is it possible to extract each of them to their source directory?

Answer (score 0):

Without the preceding `/`, it's a relative path, which means they will extract to the current directory where you run the `tar -xf` command.

Either run the `tar -xf` extract command from `/` or use the `-C /` option to change to `/` before extracting. As-always, checkout `man tar` for details.

Answer (score -1):

OK, found solution myself.

--absolute-names  option must be used BOTH when you create archive, as well as when you extract it. Works perfect. THANKS anyway!